# Mongodb cursor iteration slow

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am querying data from mongodb in chunks having 100M + records in total. And then want to process those records within a function.

My query

```
cursor = collection.find({'facial_task':False}).sort("_id", -1).skip(1000000).limit(10000)
```

When I iterate over the `cursor`, then it is taking too much time and gets stuck a lot even I limit the number of results up to 10. I even retrieved the results using batch size but when processing the loop over it; it takes too much time.

My loop is like this

```
for dd in cursor:
            ab = threading.Thread(target=insert_func, args=(dd,)) 
            ab.start()
            main_threads.append(ab)
            if len(main_threads) >= 5000:
                print("****Joining Main Thread***")
                for ii in main_threads:
                    ii.join()
                main_threads = []
```

Comment: What does `insert_func` do?

Comment: It process the data it gets and dumps in a seperate db

Comment: Can that processing be done by an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: no I don;t think so. But the issue I am facing lies even before a thread in starting. Loop stucks in the first iteration when I am debugging it

Comment: have you instrumented both the loop and the insert_func so you can tell how long each step takes?

Comment: the function downloads a file which is mostly in kbs and updates the mongo record which is passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229764/discussion-between-veerg404-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

If the slowdown occurs from the very first iteration, then it must have to do with the cursor itself.

Mongodb cursor is not like a 'chached' list of the entire collection; it queries the db one chunk at a time as you iterate over it.
You can try to cast that cursor into a list and see if the iteration shows a significant speed-up.

Comment: The issue lies even before starting a thread; the program gets stucks in the first iteration when I am debugging this.

Comment: Thanks for update. I got you but even casting the cursor into a list also takes huge amount of time. Its not making any sense for me although I have been doing this for quiet a while but on a small set of data.

Comment: I think the issue maybe the results are not proceed and mongo may be processing the data in the backend .I even tried to lower the limit to 10 but not making any difference.

Comment: Mmh that's weird. Maybe you can set the log verbosity for mongodb to see what it's actually doing and find out in which step it hangs.